# Python : How to parse things such as : from, to, body, from a raw email source w/Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi

The raw email usually looks something like this

```
From root@a1.local.tld Thu Jul 25 19:28:59 2013
Received: from a1.local.tld (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by a1.local.tld (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id r6Q2SxeQ003866
    for <ooo@a1.local.tld>; Thu, 25 Jul 2013 19:28:59 -0700
Received: (from root@localhost)
    by a1.local.tld (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id r6Q2Sxbh003865;
    Thu, 25 Jul 2013 19:28:59 -0700
From: root@a1.local.tld
Subject: ooooooooooooooooooooooo
To: ooo@a1.local.tld
Cc: 
X-Originating-IP: 192.168.15.127
X-Mailer: Webmin 1.420
Message-Id: <1374805739.3861@a1>
Date: Thu, 25 Jul 2013 19:28:59 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="bound1374805739"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--bound1374805739
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

--bound1374805739--
```

So if I wanted to code a PYTHON script to get the

```
From
To
Subject
Body
```

Is this the code I am looking for to built on of or is there a better method?

```
a='<title>aaa</title><title>aaa2</title><title>aaa3</title>'

import re
a1 = re.findall(r'<(title)>(.*?)<(/title)>', a)
```

Comment: Ever heard of PLY or, most particularly, PyParsing? If you'll be doing lots of emails that might contain characters that wouls break a handmade parser, the two are great Python packages designed for parsing files. You might want to try PyParsing first; it's the easiest.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't really understand what your final code snippet has to do with anything - you haven't mentioned anything about HTML until that point, so I don't know why you would suddenly be giving an example of parsing HTML (which you should never do with a regex anyway).

In any case, to answer your original question about getting the headers from an email message, Python includes code to do that in the standard library:

```
import email
msg = email.message_from_string(email_string)
msg['from']  # 'root@a1.local.tld'
msg['to']    # 'ooo@a1.local.tld'
```

Comment: I choose this answer because the movement is direct rather than indirect. ( not importing parser and etc ) which is kind of welcoming.- Sumer Kolcak

Comment: How to get the body?

Answer (score 14):

Fortunately Python makes this simpler: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/email.parser.html#email.parser.Parser

```
from email.parser import Parser
parser = Parser()

emailText = """PUT THE RAW TEXT OF YOUR EMAIL HERE"""
email = parser.parsestr(emailText)

print email.get('From')
print email.get('To')
print email.get('Subject')
```

The body is trickier.  Call `email.is_multipart()`.  If that's false, you can get your body by calling `email.get_payload()`.  However, if it's true, `email.get_payload()` will return a list of messages, so you'll have to call `get_payload()` on each of those.

```
if email.is_multipart():
    for part in email.get_payload():
        print part.get_payload()
else:
    print email.get_payload()
```

Answer (score 2):

"Body" is not present in your sample email

Can use [email](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email) module :

```
import email
    msg = email.message_from_string(email_message_as_text)
```

Then use:

```
print email['To']
print email['From']
```

...
...
etc

Comment: I've been trying to build something similar, but am running into a lot of issues in Python3 -- what would be the current way to do this? I'm returning None's with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [email.parser](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/email.parser.html#email.parser.Parser)

```
s = """
From root@a1.local.tld Thu Jul 25 19:28:59 2013
Received: from a1.local.tld (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by a1.local.tld (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id r6Q2SxeQ003866
    for <ooo@a1.local.tld>; Thu, 25 Jul 2013 19:28:59 -0700
Received: (from root@localhost)
    by a1.local.tld (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id r6Q2Sxbh003865;
    Thu, 25 Jul 2013 19:28:59 -0700
From: root@a1.local.tld
Subject: ooooooooooooooooooooooo
To: ooo@a1.local.tld
Cc: 
X-Originating-IP: 192.168.15.127
X-Mailer: Webmin 1.420
Message-Id: <1374805739.3861@a1>
Date: Thu, 25 Jul 2013 19:28:59 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="bound1374805739"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--bound1374805739
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

--bound1374805739--
"""

import email.parser

msg = email.parser.Parser().parsestr(s)
help(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could write that raw content to a file

then read the file like this:

```
with open('in.txt', 'r') as file:
    raw = file.readlines()

get_list = ['From:','To:','Subject:']
info_list = []

for i in raw:
    for word in get_list:
        if i.startswith(word):
            info_list.append(i)
```

now `info_list` will be:

```
['From: root@a1.local.tld', 'Subject: ooooooooooooooooooooooo', 'To: ooo@a1.local.tld']
```

i dont see `Body:` in your raw content